# Trying to put text within the custom cursor when hovered an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

here is my current code and I need help with making text inside the cursor appear. E.g. I want to have some text, i.e. "Say Hi" inside the custom enlarged cursor. I don't know how to make text appear. I've also attached an image to show what it looks rn and how I want it to look when hovered over that element. Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
<div class="cursor"></div>


<script>
        var cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
            cursor.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
            cursor.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';

        });

        var cursor3 = document.querySelector('.cursorHover');

        cursor3.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
            var element = document.querySelector('.cursor');
            element.style.transform = 'scale(6)';
            element.style.background = '#FF6E1D';
            element.style.content = 'hello';
        });

        cursor3.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
            var element = document.querySelector('.cursor');
            element.style.transform = '';
            element.style.background = '';
                        element.style.content = '';

        })

    </script>

 <div class="div-33 ">
        <span class="span-11 cursorHover">
            <div class="div-34">
                LET’S GET SOMETHIN’
                <br />
                COOKIN’.
            </div>
            <img loading="lazy" src="imgs/im/Vector.png" class="img mt-4" />
        </span>
    </div>

    <style>
        .cursor {
            content: " ";
            position: absolute;
            background: #FF6E1D;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            border-radius: 100%;
            user-select: none;
            pointer-events: none;
            /*            mix-blend-mode: color;*/
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
            z-index: 9999;
            content: '';
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: You want `.innerText = ` (or `.textContent`) not `.style.content = `. Also a `div` is not a valid child of a `span`